# Google Sheets Import XML

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

I would like to import the "Major Market Sectors" table from the following webpage into Google Sheets. I have tried using the chrome inspector tool, as well as the XPath reference without any luck. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

webpage: https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/composition/316389303

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets IMPORTXML function only can get data included in the source code of the page, but the table you like to import is added programatically, so you should use another tool to do that.